# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument - looking for Boolean while constructor of String

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have this legacy code that complains about the creation of a bean as it seems it tries to use one constructor over the other:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'catService' defined in class path resource [catContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [boolean]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

The XML definition of the bean is like that:

```
 <bean id="catService" class="com.example.CatService" lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg  type="java.lang.String" value="${catName}" />
</bean>
```

The `catName` value is coming from another file, and here is the folder structure:
[image]

The class itself has several constructors:

```
@Autowired
public CatService(String catName) {
    ...
}

public CatService(){
 ...
}


public CatService(boolean isHungry){
   ...
}
```

Why Spring is trying to use the "wrong" constructor?

Comment: Do you have a string property/bean named `catName` anywhere?

Comment: @lealceldeiro yes, there is such a string property in another file (but IntelliJ is not recognizing it when clicking the "ctrl" -> `cannot  find declaration to go to`

Comment: @lealceldeiro the app has the same error also when running from CLI

Answer (score 0):

So after a frustrating 2 days on this, the problem was gone exactly as it came.

No code changes.

Some of the actions that I performed:

- computer restart
- `mvn clean` to the parent project
- `mvn clean` to the dependency project that caused the problem
- IntelliJ "invalidate cache & restart" several times.
- GIT "shaking" - moving back and forth between different branches

It seems like none of them did the magic on its own, though I think the main contributor was the `mvn clean` to the dependency project that caused the problem